# How to exclude a drive from an import source in Picasa

Tags: hard-drive, usb, picasa

I have a PC with an external hard drive connected via USB. It has many pictures on it because it serves as a backup for the "My Pictures" folder of the main drive.

This drive isn't "checked" as an image folder in Picasa so I don't have any problem with duplicate pictures in Picasa.

The problem I have is: when I click "Import" in Picasa, Picasa uses this USB drive as an import source by default and starts scanning it for new pictures. Each time, I have to manually select the SD card from which I really want to import.

Is there a way to exclude this drive as a possible import source? It already doesn't list the internal SATA drive (because it is fixed, presumably) and maybe there is a way to add my USB drive to a list of "ignored" drives?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried "Folder Manager" option and un-selected the USB drive before you use 'Import' option?. Try this out and check your results.

Go to Tools > Folder Manager > select "Remove from Picasa"

[image]

Is this matches your requirement?

Comment: Yes, the USB hard drive is marked as "Remove from Picasa". I believe that's why picture do not appear in duplicates in my picture gallery.
However the drive is still the first one that's scanned when I click on "import".